# What code do I need, to get the pizzas ordered from my array to reappear in a different function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

What code do I need to put in, so that it will show what pizzas have been ordered. Like in the array.
Down in the calculation function I have already got the customers name and number (and address) to show up as a receipt sort of thing. But I also need it to show what pizzas have been ordered.

So I need the variable "fullorder" to show up again in the alert in the "calculation function" If that makes any sense.

Sorry if this doesn't make a lot of sense. It is tuff trying to explain it.

```
 totalNumber = 0;   // for total number of Pizzas ordered
 pizzaPrice = 9.50;   // price of each pizza
 pizzaPriceGourmet = 15.50;  //price for gourmet pizzas
 orderTotalPrice = 0;   // total cost of order
 pizzaDeliveryPrice = 5; // price for pizza delivery
 var customerName = prompt("Please enter your name.") //prompt to get the customers name
 var customerNumber = prompt("Please enter your phone number.") //prompt to get the customers number


function order()
{
  var pizza = new Array()
  pizza[0] = document.form.hawaiian.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[0] = Number(pizza[0])                           //converts to number value
  pizza[1] = document.form.cheese.value                 //allocates type of pizza in array            
  pizza[1] = Number(pizza[1])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[2] = document.form.veggie.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[2] = Number(pizza[2])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[3] = document.form.supreme.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[3] = Number(pizza[3])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[4] = document.form.pepperoni.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[4] = Number(pizza[4])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[5] = document.form.meatlovers.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[5] = Number(pizza[5])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[6] = document.form.chicken.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[6] = Number(pizza[6])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[7] = document.form.prawn.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[7] = Number(pizza[7])                            //converts to number value

  totalPlain = pizza[0] + pizza[1] + pizza[2] + pizza[3] + pizza[4];
  totalGourmet = pizza[5] + pizza[6] + pizza[7];

  var totalNumber = totalGourmet + totalPlain

  var fullOrder = alert("You have ordered: " + "\n" +        
         "Hawaiian Pizza: " + pizza [0] + "\n" +
         "Cheese Pizza: " + pizza [1] + "\n" +
         "Veggie Pizza: " + pizza [2] + "\n" + 
         "Supreme Pizza: " + pizza [3] + "\n" +
         "Pepperoni Pizza: " + pizza [4] + "\n" +
         "Meat-Lovers Pizza: " + pizza [5] + "\n" +
         "Chicken Pizza: " + pizza [6] + "\n" +
         "Prawn Pizza: " + pizza [7]);  


  if (totalNumber >12) {          // Limit for total amount of Pizzas ordered
      alert("There is a limit of 12 pizzas per order. - PRESS 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' THEN PRESS 'cancel order' AND THEN RE-ORDER! - Current total is: " +totalNumber);
  } else 
      alert("Total number of pizzas ordered: " + totalNumber); //Total amount of pizzas ordered
  calculate()  //Begins calculation function
}


function calculate()    //Function for the cost of the order
{
    orderTotalPrice = (totalPlain*pizzaPrice + totalGourmet*pizzaPriceGourmet);  //order total+ amount of pizzas ordered * pizza price
    var pizzaDelivery = prompt('Would you like your order to be delivered for $5, or for pick up?    -Type in "1" for delivery, and "0" for pickup.') //asks if you want your order to be delivered or not
    orderTotalPrice = (orderTotalPrice + (pizzaDelivery*pizzaDeliveryPrice)); // calculates the total cost with or without the delivery cost
    alert("Total cost of pizzas is: $" + orderTotalPrice.toFixed(2) );  //Display order cost as "$"0.00
    if (pizzaDelivery == '1'){
        var response = prompt("Please enter your address: ")
        alert("The pizza should be delivered within the next 25 minutes, to this address:   " +response)
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything happens to go wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber +"\n" +response)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    } else if (pizzaDelivery == '0'){
         alert("Your order will be ready for pickup in 15 minutes!")
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything happens to go wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are very right, it doesn't make much sense. If you can simplify it a bit while preserving the problem, it'll be better.

Comment: you can just pass `fullOrder` to `calculate`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to call order function after variable declaration:

```
totalNumber = 0;   // for total number of Pizzas ordered
 pizzaPrice = 9.50;   // price of each pizza
 pizzaPriceGourmet = 15.50;  //price for gourmet pizzas
 orderTotalPrice = 0;   // total cost of order
 pizzaDeliveryPrice = 5; // price for pizza delivery
 var customerName = prompt("Please enter your name.") //prompt to get the customers name
 var customerNumber = prompt("Please enter your phone number.") //prompt to get the customers number

order();//call order
```

make your calculate to this:

```
 calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain);// while calling

function order(){
//rest of code 
if (totalNumber >12) {          // Limit for total amount of Pizzas ordered
    alert("There is a limit of 12 pizzas per order. - PRESS 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' THEN PRESS 'cancel order' AND THEN RE-ORDER! - Current total is: " +totalNumber);
    } else 
    alert("Total number of pizzas ordered: " + totalNumber); //Total amount of pizzas ordered
    calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain);  //Begins calculation function
}

function calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain)    //Function for the cost of the order
{
//current code

}
```